# Headers from bytes to ascii is not working correctly

Tags: python, sockets, header, ethernet

I've gut the current Python3 script. I copied some parts from: http://www.security.securethelock.com/packet-headers/ however when I run it myself instead of printing the destination in ASCII, it prints it in bytes? What is the problem?

```
import socket
import struct
import binascii

rawsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
rawsocket.bind(("192.168.2.4", 8000))

while True:
    pkt = rawsocket.recvfrom(2048)
    if len(pkt) > 0:
        eth_hdr = pkt[0][0:14]
        eth_hdr = struct.unpack("!6s6s2s", eth_hdr)

        destination = binascii.hexlify(eth_hdr[0])
        print(destination)

    request = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

`binascii.hexlify()` returns a bytes object; since the data consists only of ASCII digits and letters (`a` to `f`), you can safely decode that as ASCII:

```
print(destination.decode('ASCII'))
```